# How do I change the width of operator popup?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

I've done this simple operator taken from templates.
How to change operator GUI width?

I tried `scale_x` and `ui_units_x` but no result. Always same GUI width.

[image]

And here the code:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    #input value
    value: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name='Value',
        description='value description',
        default=0.05, soft_min=0.00, soft_max=.2, precision=4, step=.1, unit='LENGTH')


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        box = layout.box()
        #box.scale_x = 3.0
        box.ui_units_x = 300.0
        box.prop(self, 'value')


    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, 'Value: '+str(self.value))        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: That's no pup-up, it's the *redo panel* and setting its size is not possible atm hence no answer I guess.